# CSS styling for all cells in a table

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a style to all cells (td elements) inside a given table, and not any other tables. Is there a way to do this in CSS without having to specify a class for each td in the table I want to apply the style to?

For example, let's say I want to make all cells in a particular table have a padding of 3px on all four edges. To do this for every td I could declare:

```
td { padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; }
```

Problem: this applies to every single td on the page. I just want to apply to this a single, named table, or alternatively, to all tables of a given class.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#someTable td { padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; }
```

This will apply your style to only a specific table

```
.someTable td { padding: 3px 3px 3px 3px; }
```

This will apply the change to all tables with the given class

Answer (score 2):

As others have answered, having the ***td*** element's styles declared as a **descendant selector** (learn more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)) or a **child selector** (learn more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors)) belonging to a parent selector, instead of declaring them without the hierarchy would solve your problem.

The only thing I'd like to add is that the descendant and child selectors operate with a slight difference as mentioned below in the comments below:

```
.my_table_class td { padding: 3px; } // will apply to all td elements underneath
                                     // .my-table-class (also to tables nested
                                     // below)


.my_table_class > td { padding: 3px; } // will apply to td elements immediately
                                       // under .my-table-class
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the > notation.

Answer (score 1):

add class to or id to table that you want to target for example

```
.yourTableClass td{Your Style here}
```

Comment: I tried this but cannot get it to work. Here is my test code:

'<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 td { font-weight: bold; }
 .test td { color: red; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="test">
  <tr>
   <td>hello</td>
   <td>world</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>'

If it works as I understood it, the cell text should be red.

Comment: your are using ".test" for Id  you need to use "#test" for here is working demo http://jsfiddle.net/TAnPx/

Comment: Okay I see, your original answer used a class. Now I understand. Much obliged!

Comment: and one important thing there is difference between id and class , class define with Dot "." and id with "#" hope you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Use This.
     td.tbl_class{your style;}